# Noscript DISABLED on tor 8.0.8

Tags: firefox, noscript, certificate

Noscript is completely disabled/turned off in Tor 8.0.8 and there is no way to turn it back on. I have tried reinstalling. If I try to install any version of Noscript on the firefox addon store, Tor blocks it as well.

On ADDONS the default Noscript 10.2.4 is put under "Unsupported" and gives the message "Noscript could not be verified for use in Tor Browser and has been disabled"

What is the problem here?

Comment: This issue is suspect. I started TOR, and found NoScript disbled. So I started FireFox, and NoScript was working just fine. Now all of a sudden NoScript became 'disabled' in FireFox ??? There's a big time difference between my having found it disabled in TOR, and the 'later disablement' in FireFox. If anything, it should have been disabled in FireFox first, and then in TOR.

Comment: I have the same question. Looking forward to a meaningful answer and guidance.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a problem with Tor, but within Firefox. One of the certificates which Firefox uses for signing of add-ons is expired. They write about it in their bugtracking system: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548973
Hopefully this will fixed within the next hours.

Tor also has the entry [#30388](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/30388) in their bug tracker.

So basically we all have to wait for a fix from Firefox. A short time fix to enter `about:config` into the URL bar and enter the settings. Look for the setting:

```
xpinstall.signatures.required
```

and set it to *false*. After restarting Tor Browser (and other Firefox) browsers everything works again. However please make sure that this setting is reset after a fix from Firefox.